# Adding volley response to global variables

Tags: android, android-volley

I have using volley library for fetching data. I used a HashMap to store response data. When I fetch the data out of the volley request it is showing empty. I knew I should use this Hashmap inside the response method. But I need to get that in a global variable. Any suggestions?

```
    String liveURL = BASE_URL + "livescores?api_token=" + API_KEY;

    HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        JsonObjectRequest livescoresRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                liveURL, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                      final JSONArray liveArray = response.getJSONArray("data");

                      for (int i = 0; i < liveArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject data = liveArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String liveID = data.getString("id");
                        final String league_id = data.getString("league_id");
                        hashMap.put(league_id, liveID);
                      }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error", error.toString());
                  }
                });
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(livescoresRequest);

        Log.i("HASHMAP", hashMap.toString());
```

Comment: create interface callback

Comment: Suggest me a perfect link

Comment: follow this tutorial: https://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: It is same as like my coding. How can I save the response in a global variable in the suggested tutorials

Comment: You can save on class Application, Shared Preferences, sqlite, or room, so many ways.